# Can i serialize and deserialize a DataRowView from a WPF ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, serialization, combobox

I'm filling the itemssource of a WPF combobox in code-behind with a datatable containing the columns "Listkey" and "Listvalue" like that:

```
SetElementProperty(element, "ItemsSource", (new ListtablesRead()).ReadListtable(changeTextProperties.SelectedListTable).DefaultView);
SetElementProperty(element, "DisplayMemberPath", "Listvalue");
SetElementProperty(element, "SelectedValuePath", "Listkey");
```

SetElementProperty is a method which checks by reflection, if the frameworkelement (in that case the combobox) has the given property and sets it.

Then i want to serialize the control with XmlWriter.
So i wrote a converter class for the type DataRowView:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WPFDesignerConverterLibrary
{
    public class DataRowViewConverter : ExpressionConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Finds out if the converter can convert an expression-object to the given destinationtype.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">An ITypeDescriptorContext-interface which provides a context for formatting.</param>
        /// <param name="destinationType">A type-class which represents the target-type of the conversion.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns an object of type bool. True = the destinationtype can be converted.</returns>
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(MarkupExtension))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the expression to the given destinationtype.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">An ITypeDescriptorContext-interface which provides a context for formatting.</param>
        /// <param name="culture">The System.Globalization.CultureInfo which is actually used as culture.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The object to convert.</param>
        /// <param name="destinationType">A type-class which represents the target-type of the conversion.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value,
            Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(MarkupExtension))
            {
                DataRowView datarowview = value as DataRowView;
                if (datarowview == null)
                    throw new Exception();
                return datarowview.Row;
            }

            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
}
```

This converter works and produces the following lines in the serialized XML:

```
  <sd:DataRow RowError="">
    <sd:DataRow.ItemArray>
      <x:Array Type="s:Object" xml:space="preserve"><s:String>01</s:String><s:String>Ersttest                      </s:String></x:Array>
    </sd:DataRow.ItemArray>
  </sd:DataRow>
  <sd:DataRow RowError="">
    <sd:DataRow.ItemArray>
      <x:Array Type="s:Object" xml:space="preserve"><s:String>02</s:String><s:String>Wiederholungstest             </s:String></x:Array>
    </sd:DataRow.ItemArray>
  </sd:DataRow>
  <sd:DataRow RowError="">
    <sd:DataRow.ItemArray>
      <x:Array Type="s:Object" xml:space="preserve"><s:String>03</s:String><s:String>Konstanzprüfung               </s:String></x:Array>
    </sd:DataRow.ItemArray>
  </sd:DataRow>
```

But when i try to reload the serialized XML i get an error message, which says, that no standard constructor for the type DataRow was found.
What's going wrong?
And further: To set the itemssource of the combobox with a datatable's defaultview is the simplest way to do this, but can it be that i have to go another way?

InnerException: 
       =-2146233069 HResult
       Message=For the type "System. Data. DataRow" no standard constructor was found. The type can be provided with the argument or the FactoryMethod directive.
       Source=System. Xaml
       StackTrace:
            at system. Xaml. Pattern. XamlTypeInvoker. DefaultCtorXamlActivator. EnsureConstructorDelegate (XamlTypeInvoker type)
            at system. Xaml. Pattern. XamlTypeInvoker. CreateInstance (Object [] of argument)
            at MS.Internal. Xaml. Run time. ClrObjectRuntime. CreateInstanceWithCtor (XamlType xamlType, Object [] args)
            at MS.Internal. Xaml. Run time. ClrObjectRuntime. CreateInstance (XamlType xamlType, Object [] args)

Comment: That's because `DataRow` constructor is `private`. You need to use different data type.

Comment: Thank You XAMIMAX. That means i have to go another way in filling the combobox and serializing it. Can You give me a hint please?

Comment: You need to create a class with appropriate properties, in your case it's only 2, and it will have to have public parameterless constructor. Before I can answer your question, could you tell me how do you get your data in the first place? That is before you serialize it? Thanks

Comment: I get the datatable from a SQL-request on a SQL-server-database. Then i try to set the itemssource of the Combobox with the datatable's DefaultView. All this happens before the serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile i have found another way.
I'm using a dummy-class called KeyAndValue:

```
/// <summary>
/// Dummy class with key and value properties for construction of comboboxitems.
/// </summary>
public class KeyAndValue
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the key.
    /// </summary>
    public string Key { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value.
    /// </summary>
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

That class helps to fill the items-collection of the combobox:

```
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        // Add new pairs with Listkey and Listvalue as content to the Items-collection.
        customComboBox.Items.Add(new KeyAndValue() { Key = row["Listkey"].ToString(), Value = row["Listvalue"].ToString() });
    }
```

That's a little bit like using KeyValuePair with one diffenrence: A generic list like KeyValuePair cannot be serialized.
But my dummy-class does it.

Comment: That's basically what my answer was going to be

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to have a class with parameterless contrsuctor aka `Default Constructor` that will allow `Serialization`.
Step 1.
Create a `class` to hold your database results.

- You can do this through manual code or you could use [DataSet](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dataset).

Step 2.
After you created the class or used the dataset serialize it.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(savePath + "\\" + a.Location + ".bin", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
try
{
    serializer.Serialize(fs, a);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //handle your fail;
}
finally
{
    fs.Close();
}
```

or deserialize it:

```
List<Model.YOURCLASS> _l = new List<Model.YOURCLASS>();
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pathToSearch);
FileStream fs;
BinaryFormatter deserializer = new BinaryFormatter();
foreach (var a in files)
{
    if(Path.GetExtension(a) == ".bin")
    {
        fs = new FileStream(a, FileMode.Open);
        _l.Add((Model.YOURCLASS)deserializer.Deserialize(fs));
    }
}
return _l;
```

The type that your routine returns doesn't have to be a `DataTable` your `ListView` will automatically use any collection you pass it, even an `array[]`